# Canvas Pixel Manipulation No ImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel

Is it at all possible to edit/read canvas pixels withouth the use of `getImageData()` and other such cross-origin issues?

Comment: Not unless you code an image decoder.

Comment: @markE So is there no way for me to draw to the canvas and then read pixel by pixel what is there?

Comment: Nothing! The alternative is if you start with a .png, .jpg, etc and use a decoder to fetch the pixels--and that's no easy task.

Comment: you can get stuff you draw with getImageData(), it's just off-site images that are forbidden.

Comment: One thought...(1) Set up a server with PhantomJS (a headless browser). (2) Send your image to the server, (3) have the server use html canvas & `.getImageData` to get the pixels, and (4) serve the pixel array back to the client.

Comment: i was thinking, you can use a clear canvas and show off-site images behind the canvas using an <img> tag. you would then draw on the canvas, it would look like you're drawing on the image, and you could get the marking using the imageData interface.